# LibreOffice Calc Automatic Detection of Duplicates

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Is there any way you can automatically detect a duplicate of any previous cell, the very moment you entered the text? like when you input the word "data" it will be automatically highlighted because it already exist in a previous cell.

Comment: The auto-suggest feature will fill in text (not numbers) if you have text that starts the same in another cell in the same column.  This should happen by default.  I'd suggest if you have potentially duplicate text data to enter it all in the same column.  If you are working with numbers, maybe format the column as text before you start your data entry.  (Depending on what you are doing with the numbers formatting as text might cause other problems, though.)